# Issues with Python tabula-py, error "unknown location"

Tags: python, tabula-py

I installed tabula-py using pip install, and importing it gave no errors.

I also made sure JAVA was added to PATH (environment variable).

However, when I try to run:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
```

I get the error:
*ImportError: cannot import name 'read_pdf' from 'tabula' (unknown location)*

Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

I am using Pycharm if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to give a file name to java/python argument.
You can locate your file by commanding

```
find . -name
```

and type cd and drag your file where your Pycharm project is at
so that it automatically gives you the file name after cd. like

```
ex)) cd /User/wasabi/PycharmProjects/pythonsample2/
```

and after you command terminal to start using your JAVA/Python/ whatever, you can do

```
from tabula import read_pdf
```

I'm not an expert, but I solved the issue like yours in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the parentheses on the import command

```
from tabula import read_pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I didn't have the () - I'll edit my question